# Is this statement about connected components of attractors true or known?

Tags: convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

I have a conjecture, which belongs in the field of chaos theory, as far as I can tell.

First some definitions:

- Let $B(0,1)$ be a ball in a finite-dimensional space of dimension greater than 1.
- Let $f: {B(0,1)} \times {\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow {B(0,1)}$ be a continuous surjective function such that:

  - $f(f(x,t_1),t_2) = f(x,t_1+t_2)$ for all x,$\text{ }t_1$ and $t_2$
  - for all $x_1, x_2: f(x_1, \mathbb{R}) \cap f(x_2, \mathbb{R}) = \emptyset  $ or $f(x_1, \mathbb{R}) = f(x_2, \mathbb{R})$
- Regularity on $f$

  - $\frac{df}{dt}$ is define on a dense, connected area, is continue and always of norme 1
  - at x fixed either $f(x, \mathbb{R})$ is a point either for all t: $\frac{df}{dt}(x,t)$ is define
- Let $A$ be the ***attractor*** of $f$ which I define as follows:
  $$ u\in A \iff \exists x, (t_n)\rightarrow +\infty: f(x,t_n)\rightarrow u.$$
- What I call ***inside*** in the following, I can’t define, but this is an example: The inside of a circle in 2D space is the disk with its border. In 3D space, the inside of the circle is the circle himself.
- $P\subset A$ is a ***maximally connected attractive component*** of $A$, iff:

  - there is no connected component of $A$ such that $P$ is in the *inside* of this subset, with the exception of $P$ itself,
  - there is an $x$ in the *outside* of $P$ and $(t_n)\rightarrow +\infty$ such that: $f(x,t_n)\rightarrow u \in P$

Now the conjecture: **The attractor has one maximally connected attractive component.**

This result would be incredibly important for me. 
Is it true? Does it already exist? Any idea of a proof?
I encourage you to make drawing to convince you or find a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, attractors are required to be minimal by definition, i.e., an attractor¹ must not have a true subset that is also an attractor¹.

Your definition of attractor is missing this and hence the union of all attractors (usually called the attracting set) is also an attractor² in your sense.
If you can find two or more distinct attractors¹ for your system, i.e., you have a multistable system, each of them would be a maximally connected attractive component in your sense.
However, the union of all attractors would also be an attractor² and consist of two or more maximally connected attractive components.

To give a specific example, for $\dot{x} =-x(x-1)(x+1)$, both $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are maximally connected attractive components and $\{-1,1\}$ is an attractor².
While this example is one-dimensional, it works in an arbitrary number of dimensions.
You can just add $\dot{y} = -y$ and so on as additional components, or you can build arbitrary multistable examples [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2685276/65502) (scaled down to fit inside your ball):

[image: Example of two limit cycles]

If, on the other hand, you additionally require that an attractor¹ must not have a true subset that is also an attractor¹, you immediately get that an attractor¹ consists of exactly one connected component. If it consisted of two connected components, each of them would be an attractor¹, which the requirement forbids. Thus your conjecture would hold even without considering maximality and attractiveness: An attractor¹ has one connected component. It is maximal (as per your definition) through uniqueness and attractive per definition.

---

<sup>¹ usual definition

² your definition</sup>

Comment: Your 2D exemple have a problem, the middle path will hit the border of B(0,1) with a vector derivate it can't follow but you can tweak it by making their norme tends to 0 and it's now ok. My current definition of attractor is way too wild, i will edit to add more regularity. We can see that continuity of derivate is not enough (cause when derivate hits 0 it can do weird direction change still being continue), what is needed is continuity of direction of derivate where it's define. It will at the same time solve your 1D counter exemple (direction down to up instaneously).

Comment: @leoguillemin: *what is needed is continuity of direction of derivate* – What do you mean by that? If you are thinking about a constant sign of the derivative, what does that even mean in more than one dimension?

Comment: it means when normalize, derivate is continue, sadly even with this if x is a fixed point we can have x_n -> x x'_n-> x and lim n->inf df/dt(x_n,0) =/=  lim n->inf df/dt(x'_n,0), so sure direcion of derivate is continue but just because derivate is not define on the fixed point. So if f have a fixed point true continuity of direction of derivate cant be archieved sadly.